# Monit Seems doesn't except '@' in the conf file and consider it as a syntax error : Error: syntax error

Tags: monitoring, monitor, monit

I have the following configuration file monit:

```
check process rabbitmq-server with pidfile /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@ubuntu.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start"
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server stop"
```

When I run : sudo service monit restart

Getting this error :

```
Error: syntax error '/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@ubuntu.pid'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems if it contains special characters, u need to use quotes
"/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@ubuntu.pid"